# How can I disable snapping on one feature layer, among many feature layers on the map?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-flex-api

I'm using ArcGIS Flex API 3.1. I'd like to know if it is possible to choose the layer(s) on which I can snap the graphic I'm moving. Currently, when I activate snapping, my graphics are snapped on all feature layers of the map. I don't want this behaviour. 
I want to be able to snap only on one feature class.

Resgards

Comment: Not sure but try public static const SNAP_MODE_OFF:String = off

Comment: @Sunil This would deactivate snapping on all feature layers. I want to be able to snap on only one layer among many layers existing on the map.

Comment: @yo-haha Oh I see...I will research and let you know..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible.
See the answer on your question on the ArcGIS forum - http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/77154-Choosing-the-snapping-layer

Answer (score 1):

According to your question the possible answer :

snapDistance    property
snapDistance    :Number

Since :     ArcGIS API for Flex 2.3

The distance in pixels for snapping. To disable snapping, set this value to 0.

The default value is 15.

Details click [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-api/apiref/com/esri/ags/tools/EditTool.html)

Comment: This would deactivate snapping on all feature layers. I want to be able to snap on only one layer among many layers existing on the map